# Compiling PIE after handmade instrumentation

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation, aslr

I'm currently trying to implement rerandomizaton of code at runtime, to increase security against code reuse attacks. For this I need position independent code/executables (PIC/PIE).

One of the things I have to change in the generated code are global data references. Using the -fPIE flag they are generated as leaq relative to the instruction pointer, but since I need to shift the location of my functions at runtime I need to change this to absolute addressing. I do this by performing the following changes in the assembler output:

```
    leaq    .LC7(%rip), %rsi
```

=>

```
    leaq    .LC7, %rsi
```

This should get resolved by the compiler to a load using absolute addressing. The problem is that this is no longer valid PIE code, and the linker says that this specific relocation cannot be performed. Here is the error message I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: daugther.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
daugther.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I use the -fPIC flag (which is intended for shared objects - I do want to create a standalone executable) my instrumented code is transformed back into it's original form.

Does anybody know how I can achieve absolute addressing for global data references while keeping a position independent executable?

All compiler invocations and steps are:

```
g++ -O2 std=c++1z -fPIE -o daughter.s daughter.cpp
<do the instrumentation step>
g++ -o daughter daughter.s -pie
```

Comment: If you use absolute references to either code *or* data, doesn't that inherently conflict with the position-independence?

Comment: No it does not, since I'm not moving the data (only code) it is okay to have absolute references to data. Relative to the instruction pointer wont work, since I need to move my code (which changes the delta to the data). What I need is for the dynamic loader to resolve the relocations when the program is started and the final memory addresses are known.